# How to get a common element from 2 given Flux?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

Given 2 Flux-

```
Flux<String> flux1 = ...
Flux<String> flux2 = ...
```

Now I need to check if a common String is present in both the Flux. After checking, response could either be boolean or a `List<String>`

Comment: a `List<String>` of what, the common elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flux is a continuous stream of elements that emits 0 to N elements, and then completes (successfully or with an error). So in this case we will have to aggregate the values into a List as they become available. You can make use of `collectList()` operator of Flux.

```
public Mono<List<String>> getCommonElements(Flux<String> flux1, Flux<String> flux2) {
    return flux1.collectList().zipWith(flux2.collectList())
            .map(tuple2 -> {
                List<String> commonElements = new ArrayList<>(tuple2.getT2());
                commonElements.retainAll(tuple2.getT1());
                return commonElements;
            });
            // If you want to return a Mono<Boolean>
            // .map(List::isEmpty);
}
```

This returns a `Mono<List<String>>` on top of which you can build your further logic on.

Comment: This is a nice way to get the List. Also can you help me to check if the Mono<List<String> which I get after this is not empty? I have implemented this in a boolean method. So I need to return a boolean value if the list is not empty. {not Mono<Boolean>, I need to return a boolean value.}

Comment: Hi, We can sure update this to return a Mono<Boolean>. If you are using reactive pipeline every operation should return a publisher (i.e. Mono or Flux). The only way to make this return a `boolean` is to use `.block()` and by doing so your application is not reactive anymore.

Comment: Yeah I know  about ```.block()``` .I dont want it non-reactive.

Comment: Then you cannot expect a method to operate on Publishers and return a simple boolean. It just doesn't work that way.

Comment: Fair enough. I am new to Reactive programming so I have to make rookie mistakes to learn ;)